# Java design: Component, Model, Function

Tags: java, object

I have three types of objects:

- Components: identified by a package and a name
- Models: identified by a package and a name
- Functions: identified by a name

The relationships are defined as follows:

- A Component can have zero or more Model(s) [0..*]
- A Model can have zero or more Function(s) [0..*]
- A Function can be in one or more Model(s) [1..*]
- A Model can be in zero or more Component(s) [0..*]

The natural design would be to have Component to have a set of references to Model(s) and Model to have a set references to Function. With this design I can easily navigate relationships in a top-down fashion (and easily answer queries like: "What Function(s) are contained in this Model?".

The problem is that I need more flexibility.
I would like to have something that's easily navigable to answer these kind of queries:

1. Given a Function name, in which Models and in turn in which Components is this Function referenced?
2. Given a Model package+name, in which Components is that Model referenced?
3. Are there Models not referenced by any Component?

I've thought of having Component, Model and Function as simple POJOs and to keep track of references between them with multiple HashMaps (`HashMap<Component, Model>`, `Hashmap<Model, Component>`, `HashMap<Model, Function>`, `HashMap<Function, Model>`) but this seems inefficient to me.

Can you suggest me something better designed?

Comment: Given the way this question is laid out, it smells a bit like homework.

Comment: David, what does it mean "it smells a bit like homework"? I've tried to write the question as clearly as possible.

Comment: The questions are very specific and there is little practical application included. Plus you haven't made an attempt at them.

Comment: If this is homework, you need to add the homework tag

Comment: This is not homework, but given your comments it seems you won't believe me. David, I've added my "attempt". It's far from good design, but this is the best I could come up with.

Comment: @PietroM. I never said I won't believe you. SO gets a lot of people dumping their homework questions with little effort from them- so we tend to become a bit wary. If I was *sure* it was homework, I would have added the homework tag myself.

Comment: And why don't you simply model the associations between objects in the form of... associations between objects? A component has a Set<Model>, a Model has a Set<Component>, a Model has a Set<Function>, a Function has a Set<Model>.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I've read how homework questions are treated.
It's ok even if you have a suggestion, not the full answer. Maybe there is some data structure that I don't know about. The problem I'm seeing with my solution is mainly having two HashMaps per couple of objects when the relationships are symmetrical.

Comment: @JBNizet That's a possible solution and certainly is more correct than having relationships managed "externally" with HashMaps. But this kind of design does not discriminate between symmetrical and asymmetrical relationships: i.e. a Component can have a Model but that Model can miss the Component relationship in his own set.
Given that your solution (or the Hashmap approach) "works", I was just wondering if there was another design that could be considered more "elegant".

Comment: I don't see how it's different from your solution with maps. You just need to encapsulate the add and removal operations correctly to make sure that when you add a model to a component, this component is added to the model. Same as with your maps, where you must insert the association in two maps.

Comment: @PietroM.: why do you think your approach seems unefficient? Using Maps for unordered relationships and in particular TreeMap implementation for ordered-on-key mappings, seems an efficient approach speed-wise. If you want to persist that off-line then you'll have to use some kind of DB (relational or not). But in memory that makes total sense.

Comment: @JBNizet You're right. I need to encapsulate the add and removal operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *logical* data structure to represent your problem domain is a *graph*, but doing so literally will not provide you the "efficient" means of answering the queries you cite as examples. It would help to know whether these queries are merely examples you've thought of out of what you imagine to be a larger set, or whether they constitute a complete specification of the requirements.

I suspect you won't like this answer, but what I think you would benefit from most here is a *relational database*. You can embed one that holds all the data in memory if you prefer to avoid some of the normal complication with using such a database. *SQLite*
 is one relational database to consider, but there are many others available for use in Java.

I reach that conclusion based on your phrasing. You mention navigating the graph edges (or the aggregating relationships between the entities) in *both* directions. That's trivial to express in a relational model of the problem, but becomes very difficult when you use in-memory structures like the maps you propose; the former has no implied directionality to the foreign references among relations, whereas the latter can only represent unidirectional references from one entity to another.

In the relational model, you're able to express facts as follows:

- There are entities called *Components*, that have these properties.
- There are entities called *Models*, that have these other properties.
- There are links between *Components* and *Models*, where every *Model* is "reachable from" any number of *Components*, and every *Component* "can reach" any number of *Models*. (Note that I did not write "contained within" or "owns" or any other relationship that suggests exclusivity.)

The relational model allows one to evaluate queries against these relations without any bias as to which way the links "point." Of course, the links are assertions with some meaning—likely directional, making the logical graph a *directed* rather than an *undirected* graph—specific to your problem domain, but it's your application that understands that meaning, not the database or the relational model that governs its operation.

Beyond the logical model, answering your queries as efficiently as possible will require you to specify that the database maintain some non-constraint-based *indices*. Some of the records can be looked up efficiently without you asking for anything special beyond integrity constraints, as the database will likely build indices on its own to aid in efficient enforcement of the stated constraints. But while it may be able to tell you quickly whether there are already any pairings between a given *Component* and a *Model*, it won't be ready to answer which *Components*, if any, reference a particular *Model*.

Requesting that the database maintain such indices is akin to you maintaining some of the in-memory maps that you proposed originally, but there's a difference in the design approaches: In your design, some of the potential queries that will emerge *can't be answered at all*, because the relationships won't be captured in a way that they can be navigated, even inefficiently. With the database, though, adapting to new queries is usually a matter of defining additional indices to help speed up queries over data *that is already there*. In other words, the database can still answer your nascent queries; it just may have to struggle in embarrassing ways to do so. Not until you define the proper indices will it then be ready to handle those queries as efficiently as the others you've anticipated.

I'll make one more point here. Using a relational database here may be overkill *technically*, but it is the right *didactic* choice. It's the kind of solution that your problem deserves. You can build something more narrow, more tailored, that provides a small subset of the database's capabilities and meets your needs, but in doing so, I think you're missing out on the larger design lesson here. You will have used your problem to learn something about how to *implement* a database, rather than learning about how to *employ* a database to model your problem. Making the latter both possible and easy is the reason the industry has made such database technology available.

Comment: The queries I've listed can be considered a complete specification of the requirements.
I see your points and you're right about the scalability of your solution, but given the domain I'm working with that seems really overkill (as you've pointed out, by the way). Thanks for the exhaustive answer.

Comment: Just for general knowledge, would you suggest using a Relational DB or an Object DB? I'm not a big fan of having SQL queries hardcoded in your software and, plus, you have the overhead of DAOs...
(Does it make sense? Last time I've seen a DB was a long time ago) :)

Comment: I recommend a relational database, and, despite your stated hesitation, I would recommend *avoiding* any ORM technology here; your problem is too small to warrant all the accidental complexity that would incur. You can load in the SQL as text resources from a configuration file, if being able to adjust it post-compilation makes you feel better. Using JDBC, executing a query and collecting results usually requires around ten lines of boilerplate code. Libraries like Spring's `JdbcTemplate` provide more concise and different boilerplate.

Comment: I see, thank you for your help. Can I ask you to point me to some online resource to learn how to use SQLite in Java? I've searched for it but since it's not Java native, there are several third-party solutions (e.g.: sqlite4java, sqlitejdbc) and I don't know what to choose.

Comment: I have used both the Zentus (http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/) and the Xerial (http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC) JDBC drivers. The latter grew out of the former. Today, I recommend the Xerial driver. Once you get the right Jar file on your class path, you're free to grab generic JDBC examples; they'll pretty much all work fine with SQLite. The SQLite-specific tuning comes via its pragma statements (http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html). In short, start here (http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC#Usage) and ask more particular questions when trouble arises.

Answer (score 1):

The data structure that will allow you to track all of the relationships you describe in a single collection is a `MultiMap`. There is a discussion of Java MultiMaps in the [**Map Interface** section of the Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) (you will have to scroll down to the MultiMaps section or follow the link and search the page for MultiMap; there is no direct anchor to that section of the tutorial). There are available implementations of `MultiMap` for Java:

- [The Apache Commons Collections: **org.apache.commons.collections.MultiMap**](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html)
- [The Google Collections Library: **com.google.common.collect.MultMap**](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Using a `MultiMap`, you can create a mapping for your object types that can contain or aggregate the others:

```
//Associate multiple Models to one Component:
multiMap.put( componentD, modelN );
multiMap.put( componentD, modelO );
multiMap.put( componentD, modelP );
//Associate multiple Models to a Component (some different, some the same)
multiMap.put( componentE, modelQ );
multiMap.put( componentE, modelR );
multiMap.put( componentE, modelN ); //also associated with componentD
//And associate multiple Functions to one Model:
multiMap.put( modelQ, functionG );
multiMap.put( modelQ, functionH );
multiMap.put( modelQ, functionI );
```

You may later retrieve the `Collection` that is associated to any mapped key. Here is an example using the Apache Commons Collections `MultiHashMap`[<sup>api-doc</sup>](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiHashMap.html):

```
Collection modelFunctions = multiMap.get( modelQ );
```

This approach will make it easy to traverse top-down from `Component` to `Model` to `Function`. But you can also make it easy to perform bottom-up traversal if you add both ends of each relationship to the `MultiMap`. For example, to establish the relationship between a `Model` and a `Function`, you could:

```
multiMap.put( modelR, functionJ );
multiMap.put( functionJ, modelR );
```

Because both relationships have been mapped, you can easily retrieve all of the `Function`s contained within a `Model` (as in the example above) or just as easily retrieve all of the `Model`s that contain a `Function`:

```
Collection functionModels = multiMap.get( functionJ );
```

Of course this also means that if you want to break a relationship you must remember to remove both mappings from the MultiMap, but that is fairly straightforward. I hope this helps you -

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to *abstract* from *creation* and *quering* thus having possibility to easily *optimize* / *extend* certain implementation when it becomes bottleneck in terms of *performance* / *ease of use*.

Such interface would look like the following:

```
public interface IEntityManager {

    // methods for retrieving entities by plain queries

    Component getComponent(String package, String componentName);

    Model getModel(String package, String modelName);

    Function getFunction(String name);

    // more specific queries

    List<Component> getComponents(Function function);

    List<Model> getModels(Function function);

    // even more specific queries ...
}
```

In this way one can use this interface in the production code while providing arbitrary implementations with desired level of *performance*.

Now, concerning concrete implementation - there is slight difference depending on whether all `Component`, `Model` and `Function` instances and their relationships:

1. are created somewhere at the *beginning* of application (e.g. at the *beginning* of `main` method for *desktop app* or in the `ServletContextListener.contextInitialised` of *web app*) and are not changed during application execution
2. are created / removed / updated during application execution

Let's start from 1st case because it's simpler: one should make sure that all `Component`, `Model` and `Function` instances (and relationships between them) are known to instance of `IEntityManager` which is shared between logic using these entities. One of the most straightforward ways to achieve this is to put entity classes into the same Java package as `IEntityManager` implementation and make their constructors package-private thus moving creation logic to concrete `IEntityManager` implementation:

```
package com.company.entities;

public class Component {
    public final String package;
    public final String name;

    Component(String package, String name) {
        this.package = package;
        this.name = name;
    }

    // ...
}

// similar Model and Function class declarations

public class EntityManager implements IEntityManager {

    private final Map<Pair<String, String>, Component> components = new HashMap<Pair<String, String>, Component>();
    private final Map<Pair<String, String>, Model> models = new HashMap<Pair<String, String>, Model>();
    private final Map<String, Function> functions = new HashMap<String, Function>();

    // variation of factory-method
    public Component addComponent(String package, String name) {
        // only this EntityManager can create instances
        // so one can be sure all instances are tracked by it
        final Component newComponent = new Component(package, name);
        components.put(new Pair(package, name), newComponent);
    }

    // ... addModel, addFunction methods

    public void addFunctionToModel(Function function, Model model) {
        // here one should store 'somehow' information that function is related to model
    }

    public void addModelToComponent(Model model, Component component) {
        // here one should store 'somehow' information that model is related to component
    }

    // ... other methods
}
```

Please note, that in the 1st case (all entities are created at the beginning of application) one can also use **Builder** pattern to create instance of `EntityManager` class - this will clearly abstract creation logic from usage. In the 2nd case, however, one should have methods like `addComponent`, `addModelToComponent` in the class (for multi-threaded usage of single instance of `EntityManager` one should consider making methods modifying it's state **thread-safe**).

And finally, concerning how exactly one should store relationships between entities: *there is no silver bullet* for efficient storing / retrieving entities with such relationships. I would say, that if one has not more than 1000 entities with not so many relationships - search in `HashMap<String, Function>` will be quite fast and shouldn't be a bottleneck. And if it becomes bottleneck, one should inspect thoroughly which kind of queries are used more often and which are used rarely and based on that observations tune the `EntityManager` inner implementation - hence the suggestion to abstract everything behing `IEntityManager` interface.

Concerning instance of `EntityManager` in application - obviously, there should be only one instance of it (unless one has very special case). One can achieve this using `Singleton` pattern (less preferred solution, though it may work fine for some time), or simply instantiating `EntityManager` at the *beginning* of application and passing explicit instances to classes / methods which need it (more preferred solution).

Hope this helps ...